# Get all combinations of a character vector

Tags: r, loops, combinations, tidyeval, quosure

I am trying to write a function to dynamically group_by every combination of a character vector.

This is how I set it up my list:

```
stuff <- c("type", "country", "color")
stuff_ListStr <- do.call("c", lapply(seq_along(stuff), function(i) combn(stuff, i, FUN = list)))
stuff_ListChar <- sapply(stuff_ListStr, paste, collapse = ", ")
stuff_ListSym <- lapply(stuff_ListChar, as.symbol)
```

Then I threw it into a loop.

```
b <- list()
for (each in stuff_ListSym) {
  a <- answers_wfh %>% 
    group_by(!!each) %>% 
    summarize(n=n())
  b <- append(b, a)
}
```

So essentially I want to replicate this

```
...     group_by(type),

...     group_by(country),

...     group_by(type, country),
```

... and the rest of the combinations. Then I want put all the summaries into one list (a list of tibbles/lists)

It's totally failing. This is my error message:
`` Error: Column `type, country` is unknown ``.

Not only that, `b` is not giving me what I want. It's a list with length 12 already when I only expected 2 before it failed. One tibble grouped by 'type' and the second by 'country'.

I'm new to R in general but thought tidy eval was really cool and wanted to try. Any tips here?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a problem of standard evaluation. `!!` is sometimes not enough to unquote variables and get `dplyr` to work. Use `!!!` and `rlang::syms` for multiple unquotes

```r
b <- list()
for (each in stuff_ListSym) {
  a <- answers_wfh %>% 
    group_by(!!!rlang::syms(each)) %>% 
    summarize(n=n())
  b <- append(b, a)
}
```

I think `lapply` would be better in your situation than `for` since you want to end-up with a `list`

Since you use variable names as arguments of functions, you might be more comfortable with `data.table` than `dplyr`. If you want the equivalent `data.table` implementation:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(answers_wfh)
lapply(stuff_ListSym, function(g) answers_wfh[,.(n = .N), by = g])
```

You can have a look at this [blog post](https://linogaliana.netlify.app/post/datatable/datatable-nse/) I wrote on the subject of SE vs NSE in `dplyr` and `data.table`

Answer (score 1):

I think `stuff_ListStr` is enough to get what you want. You cold use `group_by_at` which accepts character vector.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

purrr::map(stuff_ListStr, ~answers_wfh %>% group_by_at(.x) %>% summarize(n=n()))
```

---

A better option is to use `count` but count does not accept character vectors so using some non-standard evaluation.

```
purrr::map(stuff_ListStr, ~answers_wfh %>% count(!!!syms(.x)))
```